# linq to sql select distinct and count of distinct

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-sql

I'm struggling creating a linq2 sql query. I have a table that contains records of media. One of the columns is media type e.g. CD, DVD etc.

I need to pull a list that will give me each of the media types that exist (Select Distinct(mediatype)) and also a count of that media type (Count(mediatype))

I've been able to create a distinct list but can't seem to figure out how to incorporate the count.
I have...

```
Dim medialist = (From m In dc.tbDatas
                 Select m.mediatype).Distinct()
```

Any help appreciated.

UPDATE...
This is my latest query

```
Dim meadialist = (FROM m In dc.tbDatas
                  WHERE m.PassFail = True AndAlso m.DateProcessed.HasData
                  Group By m Into Group
                  Select MediaType = m.MediaType, MediaCount = Group.Count()).ToArray()
```

UPDATE 2....
This is the query that gave the results I needed... i.e. a list of MediaType and a count of that media type.

```
Dim meadialist = (FROM m In dc.tbDatas
                  WHERE m.PassFail = True AndAlso m.DateProcessed.HasData
                  Group By m.MediaType Into Group
                  Select MediaType, MediaCount = Group.Count()).ToArray()
```

Comment: `Dim medialistCount = medialist.Count()` ? or are you trying to count the number of each distinct media?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to count the number of distinct media:

```
Dim medialistCount = medialist.Count()
```

If you're trying to count the number of each media type:

```
Dim medialist = (From m in dc.tbDatas 
    Group By m Into Group
    Select MediaType = m.mediatype, MediaTypeCount = Group.Count()).ToArray()
```

The second linq query groups and counts each type of media type into an array of anonymous types.

```
For Each m in medialist
    Console.WriteLine(m)
Next
```

Sample Outputs:

```
{ MediaType = Type1, MediaTypeCount = 2 }
{ MediaType = Type2, MediaTypeCount = 1 }
```

Comment: @Mych - Was this along the lines of what you were looking for?

Comment: Jason, Thanks.. its the second option I need. I've tried the code you suggested but the results I'm getting are not quite right... I'm getting: Several rows with MediaType = CD and Count 1. Could this be because of the additional where statement... I've updated my q with the latest statement.

Comment: Any chance the several rows with MediaType = CD have different cases or whitespace ("CD", "cd", "CD ")?

Comment: No... values populated from a dropdown when records created so are consistant... it was the where statement. Fixed by changing the group by and select segments to Group By m.MediaType Into Group... Select MediaType, MediaTypeCount = Group.Count().... Thanks for your help.